# Outlook Web App gives incomplete result with the search function

Tags: search, outlook-on-the-web

I noticed recently that the searches I perform in my Outlook Web Application (Exchange 2010) are not correct.

Example:

- If I perform a search of a recent email (less than 2 months for example) the search finds the email (based on a text in the title or body).
- If I perform a search of an older email (1 year ago for example) the search doesn’t find any email.

I am pretty sure I was able to perform a search in all my mailbox content in the past (emails from last week or emails from 2 years ago).

Something is strange with the search results.